where does sqitch store it's applied migrations?
I have applied migrations with sqitch, when I apply them again, it says that they have already been applied, which is true.
I did drop database <respective database> , so the database is gone, but when I apply migrations once again, it still says that they have already been applied, what means that the state of migrations is not stored within the database, but rather somewhere. Where is it? The folder with .plan and .conf doesn't have anything either.
Thanks
